# Linux Shell : tail a log file and send each line to http service using curl

Tags: linux, shell, curl, logging, tail

I'm collecting logs and need to send the logs to a real-time log monitor system.
The log monitor system  receives messages via http service.

This command works:

```
tail -F app.2015-02-17.log | sed -e "s/\"//g" |  awk '{print "{\"topic\":\"EC_IPService_Log\",\"message\":\""$0"\"}"}'|while read LINE ; do (curl -X POST -H "Authorization:Basic cm9ja2V0bXE6cm9ja2V0bXE=" -H "mq-version:1" -H "Content-Type:application/json"  http://localhost:9999/MQ/sendMessage -d "$LINE") ; done
```

The question is this command do not run fast enough to handle log from tail command, so it's getting slower and slower. When I run this command for 10 hour, it may handler the log one hour ago...

If I change curl command to echo like this:

```
tail -F app.2015-02-17.log | sed -e "s/\"//g" |  awk '{print "{\"topic\":\"EC_IPService_Log\",\"message\":\""$0"\"}"}'|while read LINE ; do (echo "$LINE") ; done
```

This command run fast enough.

Is there any better solution to use curl to solve this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd better omit your Authorization Header.

Comment: Well sure, `echo` is faster than `curl`, which is making a network connection, with security checking. I don't see how you can get around that, short of sending "chunks" of you file via curl (or other methods). Good luck.

Comment: You might also check the response headers, some services engage rate limiting to prevent the application from being flooded. [For example](https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/)